# Get name of the row in dataframe (python pandas)

Tags: python, loops, pandas

For example I have a dataframe, which has 5 rows and 5 columns. The have the same name. Example:

...A  B  C  D  E

A  0  0  0  0  0

B  0  0  0  0  0

C  0  0  0  0  0

D  0  0  0  0  0

E  0  0  0  0  0

How I can make the loop through my dataframe to compare column name and row name in order to set value of 1 where col and row names are equal.

...A  B  C  D  E

A  1  0  0  0  0

B  0  1  0  0  0

C  0  0  1  0  0

D  0  0  0  1  0

E  0  0  0  0  1

Comment: Or may be I should use another structure for such task? Further I would need that data for Data Analysis

Comment: The main point is to get the method of how to get column name and row name

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjspJ_CwZLLAhWmYpoKHUZeDpoQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.fill_diagonal.html&usg=AFQjCNH-YC4kgtpaMPCozJl84OXckvGxzg&bvm=bv.115277099,d.bGs) for your values of dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), index=list("ABCDE"))

In [37]: np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 1)

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
   A  B  C  D  E
A  1  0  0  0  0
B  0  1  0  0  0
C  0  0  1  0  0
D  0  0  0  1  0
E  0  0  0  0  1
```

**EDIT**

If you need to fill values where rows and column indices are the same you could use slice your values of the diagonal where that's true and assign to it whatever you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), index=list("ABCGE"))
mask = df.columns == df.index
df.values[mask, mask] = 1

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
   A  B  C  D  E
A  1  0  0  0  0
B  0  1  0  0  0
C  0  0  1  0  0
G  0  0  0  0  0
E  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: I think this doesnt work, because if you change df like `df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), index=list("ABCGE"))`, output is same. You only add `1` to diagonal and OP need comparing.

Comment: My answer addresses that -- although it was not clear what OP needed.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for pointing that out. Edited version should work.

Comment: but what if column length is not equal to index length? what if I need to see if A == C then make the value equal to 1. The main point was how I can compare index NAMES and column NAMES.

Comment: @user3828374 `df.columns` will give you all column **NAMES**. Edit your question according to what you want and for what dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Or if your rows and columns are not ordered:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.index == row.name, axis=1).astype(int)
```

The `.astype(int)` at the end converts booleans to integers.

Comment: Also works applying by column: `df.apply(lambda col: col.index == col.name).astype(int)`.

Comment: The difference is you save 8 characters by leaving `, axis=1` out ;)

Comment: but what if column length is not equal to index length? what if I need to see if A == C then make the value equal to 1. The main point was how I can compare index NAMES and column NAMES.

Comment: My solution works just as well when the dataframe is not square. Since I'm iterating by row, `row.index` is the (scalar) value of the row's index while `row.name` is the list of column names.